# Sort an object array with a Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to sort an object array based on a Unix Timestamp. In the code below I have a function called parseFunc() that fixes the string coming from a headerless CSV file and rebuilds it into a format that I need.

The idea is to sort the array that comes from the CSV file into certain periods (day, week, month, year) using a Unix Timestamp as the variable to base the sorting off of. If my logic is correct, I need to do the sorting before calling the parseFunc() function.

I have tried to build a function using a filter() method

```
function getNumber(num){
  return (num == 1556015903109)
}

lines = lines.filter(getNumber);
```

this is just to see if I can create an array based on one number from the object array.

But it returns an empty object.

```
function parseFunc(readout) {
    "use strict";
    var jSON = JSON.stringify(readout),
//these are to strip the string of unwanted characters and replace
        c1 = jSON.replace("[", "{"),
        c2 = c1.replace("]", "}"),
        c3 = c2.replace(/","/g, "\"\n}{\""),

        c4 = c3.replace(/{/g, ""),
        c5 = c4.replace(/,/g, "\",\""),
        c6 = c5.replace(/}/g, ""),
        c7 = c6.replace(/"/g, "");


// These are to separate the elements of the array and build JSON strings in a particular order.
    const pL = c7.trim().split('\n').map(row => {
        const cols = row.split(',')
        return { label: cols.shift()}

    });

    const pT1 = c7.trim().split('\n').map(row =>{
        const cols = row.split(',')  
        const cols2 = cols.shift()
        return { value: cols.shift()}
     });

    const pT2 = c7.trim().split('\n').map(row =>{
        const cols = row.split(',')  
        const cols2 = cols.splice(0,2)
        return { value: cols.shift()}
     });

        const pT3 = c7.trim().split('\n').map(row =>{
        const cols = row.split(',')  
        const cols2 = cols.splice(0,3)
        return { value: cols.shift()}
     }); 
     const pT4 = c7.trim().split('\n').map(row =>{
        const cols = row.split(',')  
        const cols2 = cols.splice(0,4)
        return { value: cols.shift()}
     });   

}

function init() {
    "use strict";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

            var lines = this.responseText.split("\n");
            parseFunc(lines);
            console.log(lines);


        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "DemoData.csv", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Console.log(lines) gives me this data.

```
0: "1556015903109,1.7481,1.7489,1.7375,2.5631"
1: "1556015954378,1.7481,1.7336,1.7477,2.5631"
2: "1556016004213,1.7481,1.7336,1.7426,2.5631"
3: "1556016034313,1.7481,1.7489,1.7426,2.5631"
4: "1556016064425,1.7532,1.7489,1.7375,2.5631"
5: "1556016094494,1.7481,1.7489,1.7426,2.5631"
6: "1556016124586,1.743,1.7438,1.7426,2.5631"
7: "1556016154663,1.7481,1.7489,1.7426,2.5631"
8: "1556016187514,1.743,1.7336,1.7477,2.5631"
9: "1556016244923,1.743,1.7438,1.7426,2.5631"
```

element[0] is the Unix timestamp everything else is readouts.

Comment: I think it would be VASTLY simpler if you get object and keep it as such, instead of serialising into JSON and then replacing characters until you get something that is hopefully the data you want.

Comment: There has to be a javascript module that handles CSV.  Use that.

Comment: @shrewmouse I've tried several. None are helpful. I have to get it into a specific format for a paid library we use.

Comment: How is CSV - one of the simplest formats out there, not parseable by libraries that deal with CSV?

Comment: @VLAZ I don’t know what to tell you. Everything I’ve tried doesn’t do what I need it to. I’m not saying they don’t work, I’m saying I need the data a specific way. I’ve built a crude solution that works and gets the data into a format I need. Can we not split hairs about this. The question is about sorting an array, not dissecting my headache inducing code.

Comment: OK...so what *is* your input data?

Comment: @VLAZ it comes from a csv file that is updated periodically by a raspberry pi that takes measurements.

Comment: Do you have to use javascript?  Bash and python could do this is a heartbeat.

Comment: @shrewmouse I’m not familiar with either.

Comment: What OS are you running under?

Comment: Is this a one time thing or is this a program that you need to run all of the time?  If it's a one time thing then just import the CSV file into a spreadsheet and sort there.